# How to Make Links Work in WKWebView and how to correctly format words

Tags: swift, xcode

I am coding a simple app in Xcode and I have ran into a problem. I can not get links to work on the mobile app that go to other links. For example, if I click on the Twitter button at the bottom of the webpage nothing happens, I want that button to lead to the desired link it was supposed to go to. Also, the words in a page on the site are lined up in a vertical column, and I would like to know how to make the text look better in terms on formatting it correctly. Here is a picture[Picture Of Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xb0H.jpg)  [The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQdDW.png)

```
[Image]
```

Comment: If you post your code, then perhaps someone may be able to help you, otherwise there is no way of knowing what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: It would be better if you added your code as text. I don't see anything that would prevent links from redirecting. You assign self to the navigationDelegate of the webview, but don't implement its methods, so really you're not making any impact on user initiated requests. Have you tested a different url for that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're adding your WKWebView the right way and the page is loading fine. The problem with the text is actually coming from the CSS of the site as I have the problem in Safari on my phone as well, so if you are the web admin of the site I'd fix it there.

Did you try if the button you are talking about is responsive when accessing through Safari on your phone/simulator? WKWebView does not have a loading bar and it seems "unresponsive" sometimes even though the sites are loading in the back.

When adding your WebView implementation buttons like the privacy policy on the site work fine for me.

Comment: thanks for the issue on the CSS, but The social links at the bottom do not work. Is there a way to have the twitter link at the bottom go to the appropriate twitter link? same with facebook and instagram